# Possible Bug in dbms_comparison Package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I've been trying to get this comparison package running in order to compare our tables in two different databases.

I have been able to compare two tables in the same database, but if I try to get it to run over dblink to compare with another database, it gives me an error.

Here is what I do:

```
begin
dbms_comparison.create_comparison(
 COMPARISON_NAME    => 'COMPARE_TEST_REMOTE',
 SCHEMA_NAME        => 'SD',  
 OBJECT_NAME        => 'COMPARE_TEST_A',
 DBLINK_NAME        => 'PLUTODB',  
 REMOTE_SCHEMA_NAME => 'SCANKAYA', 
 REMOTE_OBJECT_NAME => 'COMPARE_TEST_B');
end;
```

which gives me:

```
Error at line 2
ORA-44004: Ungültiger qualifizierter SQL-Name
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", Zeile 315
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", Zeile 363
ORA-06512: in Zeile 2
```

Now what I understand from this error text is that, there must be a character which is not valid for SQL, but as we can see this should work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The Oracle servers have the same encoding. Check if you have set up the same encoding in DB.

Comment: You could look at bug 12592388, but that's for a name with a special character in it, doesn't involve a DB link, and is shown as fixed in 12c; only relevant thing I can see on MoS though. You may need to raise a service request to get this investigated.